# SSRS - hide a column that is currently empty because row groups are collapsed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with both row groups and column groups.  The row groups default to collapsed and can be expanded, but the column groups (that is, the column headings) are present all the time.

If every row group was expanded you would see some data in every column, but for any given row group most of the columns are empty.  Therefore I can't simply check for there to be no data in each column in the overall dataset.

I would like to automatically hide the column groups that are VISUALLY empty, in other words, that are not displaying any data at a given point in time, because all their data is contained in collapsed row group.

I recall that there are ways to access the dataset outside of the usual "Field.Value" notation, but I'm not sure how I could apply them to this situation.  It feels more like a CSS selector sort of problem.